# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy',)'

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.
I ran robot framework scripts (internally python scripts will run)

```
[2023-06-22 09:32:08.693] - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1)
[2023-06-22 09:32:08.694] - requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry - DEBUG: Incremented Retry for (url='/v1/billing/subscribers/1116cef00-22f8-4b09-834c-ac128f94df488'): RetryAdapter(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
[2023-06-22 09:32:08.694] - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - WARNING: Retrying (RetryAdapter(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa64ad7ce50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy',)': /v1/billing/subscribers/1116cef00-22f8-4b09-834c-ac128f94df488
[ WARN ] Retrying (RetryAdapter(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa64ad7ce50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy',)': /v1/billing/subscribers/1116cef00-22f8-4b09-834c-ac128f94df488
```

is this related to VM? what configs to need to be changed in VM if so?

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.